# how to get current date only in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database, where my second table has one extra column "date" and I want to copy my first table data to second with current date

so I tried this SQL SERVER query
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1, GETDATE();

and I get an error invalid object name 'GETDATE'.

Comment: That's invalid SQL. The `FROM` clause specifies the *sources* of data: tables, subqueries, table-valued functions. If you want to include a value in the results put it in `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify any values you want to include in the `SELECT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (Field1,Field2,Date)
SELECT Field1,Field2,GETDATE()
FROM TABLE1;
```

The `FROM` clause is only used to specify the query's data sources: tables, subqueries, table-valued functions.

Comment: if I have like 20-30 columns I have to declare all the column is there short form for it